# Read Matlab 2D array to intel-fortran and write from intel-fortran to matlab file

Tags: arrays, matlab, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I am using Intel Fortran with Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

My main question is: I would like to read 2D array from Matlab .mat file into fortran. Also, save the output of Fortran 2D matricies to a preferably .mat file, as currently I can save it to a text file using:

```
write(unit = #, <linelength>F22.8>),matrixname
```

This line works, but I am not sure if loose any of my double precision. If I do not loose precision, I can stick to it, otherwise I would need help. And I will only need a way to read from a Matlab file to intel-fortran with keeping the precision. There is no characters in these arrays, they are of numerical values.

I need to conserve the precision, since I am working with spherical functions, and they can be highly divergent.

Comment: The Mathworks publish extensive, and generally very good, documentation for their products.  I'm sure that a search will find you references to show you how to read and write mat files with Fortran programs.  I am confident too, that the documentation will be as detailed and as specific as you could want.

Comment: If you are using `allocatable`, it is Fortran 90 or newer. Welcome. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The site is good for answering specif questions. But your question is not very specific, it asks to write a whole tutorial for you. It also contains several separate points. I think it is too broad for this site. Try to make it shorter and more specific. I already made it somewhat shorter for you.

Comment: answering one part of the question, yes you are loosing precision if you use a text file for data transfer.

Answer (score 2):

matlab's internal ".mat" is "maybe" or "maybe not" compressed depending on versions. I think you do not want to use this for portable file transfer. ( Having attempted to find good documentation on the subject I wonder if @HPM was being sarcastic in his comment.. )

A keep it simple approach for a single array is to simply exchange as raw binary.

Example write in matlab:

```
a=[1. 2. ; 3. 4. ]
fileID = fopen('test.bin','w');
fwrite(fileID,a,'double');
fclose(fileID);
```

then in fortran

```
implicit none
double precision a(2,2)
open(unit=100,'test.bin',access='stream',form='unformatted')
read(100)a
```

note here the data is actually "flat", the reading program needs to know the array dimension. You can of course write the dimensions to the file if you need.

there are of course a number of potential portability issues with binary data, but this will work for most cases assuming you are reading/writing on the same hardware.

Comment: *I wonder if @HPM was being sarcastic in his comment*  Not at all.